# What is the procedure for profiling under GHC 7.10.1 and cabal 1.23?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc, cabal-install

What is the recommended procedure for profiling under GHC 7.10.1 and cabal 1.23? The profiling-related error and warning messages from GHC and cabal-install are very inconsistent.

1. Try to run an executable with profiling, and you are told:

   ```
   $ prediction-interactive +RTS -p

   prediction-interactive: the flag -p requires the program to be built with -prof
   ```
2. Put `-prof` in your cabal file, and you are told:

   ```
   $ cabal build

   Warning: 'ghc-options: -prof' is not necessary and will lead to problems when
   used on a library. Use the configure flag --enable-library-profiling and/or
   --enable-executable-profiling.
   ```
3. Follow that advice (and remove -prof from the cabal file), and you are told:

   ```
   $ cabal configure --enable-executable-profiling

   Resolving dependencies...
   Configuring creatur-wains-prediction-1.0...
   Warning: The flag --enable-executable-profiling is deprecated. Please use
   --enable-profiling instead.
   ```
4. Follow that advice, and you are told:

   ```
   $ cabal configure --enable-profiling

   Resolving dependencies...
   Configuring creatur-wains-prediction-1.0...

   $ cabal build

   . . .
   Installing executable(s) in
   /home/eamybut/nosync/sandboxes/prediction-wains/bin
   Installed creatur-wains-prediction-1.0

   $ prediction-interactive +RTS -p

   prediction-interactive: the flag -p requires the program to be built with -prof
   ```

Facepalm!

**EDIT**: Added cabal build in step 4.

Comment: And if you run `cabal build` now?

Comment: @ReidBarton, I did do a second cabal build (just forgot to mention it), and it ran without errors. I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the executable that was just built, rather than one that was installed to your PATH earlier? (You can use `cabal run -- +RTS -p` to run the executable that cabal has just built, or invoke it via its path `dist/...`.)

Comment: @ReidBarton Now *that's* interesting... Although I omitted it above, I was actually running the executable by pointing to the binary in the `bin` directory in the sandbox. That binary has the timestamp of the last time I changed anything and did `cabal build`. But now when I run it using `cabal run -- +RTS -p`, it creates a new executable, which does work, and I get profiling info as expected. Maybe `cabal build` doesn't produce a new executable unless there's been a change in *source* code (as opposed to a change to the cabal file)? I'll have to experiment.

Comment: I don't use sandboxes much but I wouldn't expect `cabal build` to ever install anything into the sandbox. So that part has me a bit confused. I expect `cabal build` to build an executable to `dist/build/foo/foo` and for `cabal run` to run that executable.

Comment: @ReidBarton Now that you say it, that makes sense. But I'd always thought of the `dist` directory as being full of stuff I don't need to see. In my mind `dist` had nothing to do with sandboxes, since sandboxes didn't exist in the beginning. With non-sandboxed builds, any executable produced goes into your `.cabal/bin`. So then when sandboxes became a thing, there was this new directory (the sandbox), and I expected the executable to go there.

Comment: Right, but the executables only go to `.cabal/bin` on `cabal install`, not `cabal build`. And `cabal install` with a sandbox installs the executable into the sandbox, so I wouldn't expect `cabal build` to touch the sandbox at all.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: @ReidBarton as you seemed to answer the question with your comment, perhaps you can post it as an answer?